# Swagger validation sensitivity when using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, aws-api-gateway

So I can use aws cli to import an API using its swagger yml file and it works after a bit of sensitivity, but then the same file fails when I try to do it using boto3

The code looks like this

```
client.import_rest_api(
  failOnWarnings=False, 
  parameters={}, 
  body="file://C:/somewhereinmyfilesystem/myvalidswagger.yml")
```

all the code is on the same line, I just broke it over to show on here.

Any ideas what's wrong with the command? The file works fine direct from the cli, and the error I get back when I run the python file is consistent.

Is "Invalid Swagger 2.0 input," the new "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"? Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 0):

This method should be taking **bytes** or file as the input of the body.

In you put `file://C:/somewhereinmyfilesystem/myvalidswagger.yml` as the body, it will send `file://C:/somewhereinmyfilesystem/myvalidswagger.yml` directly to API Gateway.

You can load the content in the file into a local variable, and send as bytes or you can send a **file** object.

**Sending file directly:**

```
client.import_rest_api(
    failOnWarnings=False, 
    parameters={}, 
    body=open("C:/somewhereinmyfilesystem/myvalidswagger.yml", r))
```

**Load into memory, then send:**

```
with open('C:/somewhereinmyfilesystem/myvalidswagger.yml', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

client.import_rest_api(
    failOnWarnings=False, 
    parameters={}, 
    body=content)
```